# Filtrar elementos de np.array segun otro np.array

Tags: python, numpy

poseo los siguientes np.array:

```
   CORNERS IZQ
   [array([[[1029.8044 ,  642.1538 ]],

   [[1285.3783 ,  642.90784]],

   [[1028.7731 ,  383.51373]],

   [[1293.2905 ,  386.25867]]], dtype=float32)]


   CORNERS DER
   [array([[[ 864.6084 ,  670.63306]],

   [[1128.2472 ,  673.0416 ]],

   [[ 856.3717 ,  408.2591 ]],

   [[1129.2834 ,  406.50616]]], dtype=float32)]


   MARKERS IZQ
   [array([[0],
   [1],
   [2],
   [3]], dtype=int32)]


   MARKERS DER
   [array([[0],
   [3],
   [5],
   [6]], dtype=int32)]
```

Los np.array "CORNERS IZQ" y "MARKERS IZQ" se crean de forma ordenada, los indices de sus elementos se corresponden. Lo mismo pasa entre "CORNERS DER" y "MARKERS DER"

Mi idea es extraer los valores de los indices CORNERS IZQ y CORNERS DER, si se da el caso que algun elemento en la lista MARKERS IZQ se encuentre en MARKERS DER.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 con_index_L=[]
        for L,i in enumerate(MARKERSIZQ[0]):
            for R,j in enumerate(MARKERSDER[0]):
                if i[0]==j[0]:
                    con_index_L.append((j[0],L,R))
        matriz=[[],[],[]]

        for element in con_index_L:
            val,L,R=element
            matriz[0].append(val)
            matriz[1].append(CORNERSIZQ[0][L][0])
            matriz[2].append(CORNERSDER[0][R][0])
        for i in matriz:
            print(i)
```

Esto me imprime lo siguiente:

```
[0, 3]
[array([1029.8044,  642.1538], dtype=float32), array([1293.2905 ,  386.25867], dtype=float32)]
[array([864.6084 , 670.63306], dtype=float32), array([1128.2834 ,  673.041], dtype=float32)]
```

El Resultado esperado seria el siguiente:

```
MARKERS CONCIDENTES
[array([[0],
[3],dtype=int32)]

CORNERS IZQ
[array([[[1029.8044 ,  642.1538 ]],
[[1293.2905 ,  386.25867]]], dtype=float32)]

CORNERS DER
[array([[[ 864.6084 ,  670.63306]],
[[1128.2472 ,  673.0416 ]], dtype=float32)]
```

Estoy seguro que numpy debe de tener una forma mucho mas prolija y eficiente que el choclo que estoy haciendo.

Se podria decir que cumple con lo cometido, aunque difiere en la salida, ya que mi codigo devuelve una lista de np.arrays (y los MARKERS COINCIDENTES como lista de ints), mientras que todas las salidas deberian ser np.array con todas las coordenadas ordenadas, y claramente la misma cantidad de elementos entre las 3, dado que cada "MARKER COINCIDENTE" tiene sus 2 pares de coordenadas

Aclaro que MARKERS IZQ y MARKERS DER tienen unas caracteristicas:

- Sus elementos nunca se repiten dentro de cada lista (ninguno tendra 2 veces [5] por ejemplo)
- Su longitud es variable y no necesariamente la misma que la otra

Muchas gracias

Comment: No acabo de entender qué debe hacer el algoritmo. Probablemente ayudaría que pusieras el código que has implementado, aunque no sea el más eficiente. Entiendo que lo primero que buscas es qué valores tienen en común MARKERS IZQ y MARKERS DER para después usar esos valores como índices para extraer las filas con esos índices de los otros dos arrays? Si esto es así, MARKERS IZQ y MARKERS DER tendrán siempre al final los mismos valores ¿no?

Comment: @abulafia Exactamente, necesito extraer los indices tal cual lo planteaste vos. Ahi reformule la pregunta y adjunte mi codigo para que sea mas claro. Gracias por el comentario!!

Answer (score 0):

El problema tiene dos partes:

1. Encontrar qué índices tienen en común MARKERS IZQ y MARKERS DER
2. Usar esos índices para seleccionar las filas correspondientes en CORNERS IZQ y CORNERS DER

Así que lo resuelvo separadamente

### 1. Encontrar elementos comunes

Python tiene el tipo de datos `set()` ideal para encontrar elementos en común (intersecciones). El problema es que tus datos de entrada tienen una estructura muy complicada. Son así:

```
MARKERSIZQ = [np.array([[0], [1], [2], [3]])]
MARKERSDER = [np.array([[0], [3], [5], [6]])]
```

Es decir, cada una de estas variables es una lista con un solo elemento y ese elemento es un array numpy. Pero ese array a su vez contiene dentro "sub-arrays" de un solo elemento.

Para convertirlo en conjunto hay que "aplanar" toda esa estructura. Para empezar seleccionar el único elemento de la lista con `MARKERSIZQ[0]` y después aplicar el método numpy `.ravel()` a ese elemento, para crear un array numpy "plano", que sería en este caso `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Una vez lo tenemos como array plano, lo convertimos en un conjunto usando `set()`

Lo mismo hacemos con `MARKERSDER` y tenemos otro conjunto. Usando el operador `&` se encuentra la intersección de los dos conjuntos y el resultado será un conjunto que contiene los índices 0 y 3.

Para poder usarlo después conviene que en vez de un conjunto sea una lista, por lo que aplicamos `list()` al resultado.

Combinando todo en una sola expresión queda así:

```
comunes = list(set(MARKERSIZQ[0].ravel()) & set(MARKERSDER[0].ravel()))
print(comunes)
```

Resultado:

```
[0, 3]
```

### 2. Seleccionar esas filas en las otras variables

Una vez tenemos en forma de lista los índices que interesan hacemos uso de la función numpy `np.take()` que sirve precisamente para lo que queremos aquí, extraer de un array dado una serie de elementos por su índice. Al igual que en el caso anterior tendremos que usar `CORNERSIZQ[0]` para acceder al array numpy, pues lo tienes metido dentro de una lista de un solo elemento. No voy a preguntar por qué. Y lo mismo para `CORNERSDER[0]` así que el código sería:

```
RESULTIZQ = np.take(CORNERSIZQ[0], comunes, axis=0)
RESULTDER = np.take(CORNERSDER[0], comunes, axis=0)

print(RESULTIZQ)
print(RESULTDER)
```

Resultado:

```
array([[[1029.8044 ,  642.1538 ]],
       [[1293.2905 ,  386.25867]]])

array([[[ 864.6084 ,  670.63306]],
       [[1129.2834 ,  406.50616]]])
```

> **Nota** Estos resultados no coinciden con los que pusiste en la pregunta como resultados esperados, pero creo que estos son los correctos y no los que pusiste en la pregunta. Revísalo por que para CORNERSDER creo que has seleccionado las filas 0 y 1 en lugar de 0 y 3.

### Un último detalle

La lista de índices coincidentes no está en el formato final que tú querías (pero el formato lista `[0, 3]` es el que necesita `np.take()`.

Puedes convertirlo al formato que quieres si creas con esa lista un `np.array()` y le aplicas un `.reshape((-1,1))`. Esto indica a numpy que el resultado tenga una columna (el `1`) y la cantidad de filas necesarias (el `-1`).

```
COINCIDENTES = np.array(comunes).reshape((-1,1))
print(COINCIDENTES)
```

Resultado:

```
array([[0],
       [3]])
```

Naturalmente no necesitas separar COINCIDENTESIZQ y COINCIDENTESDER por así decir, ya que serían iguales. Basta una sola variable.

## Ampliación. Iterando si hay más elementos

Si las listas MARKERS o CORNERS tienen varios elementos dentro, supongo que buscarás obtener como resultado otra lista cuyos elementos sean también arrays numpy.

Esto es bastante sencillo, basta retocar un poco el código antes suministrado para que lo haga sobre cada elemento de las listas de entrada. Por ejemplo así:

```
RESULTSIZQ = []
RESULTSDER = []

for izq, der, cor_izq, cor_der in zip(MARKERSIZQ, MARKERSDER, CORNERSIZQ, CORNERSDER):
  comunes = list(set(izq.ravel()) & set(der.ravel()))
  RESULTIZQ.append(np.take(cor_izq, comunes, axis=0))
  RESULTDER.append(np.take(cor_der, comunes, axis=0))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Tiene pinta que deberia funcionar, pero estoy teniendo problemas para implementar el codigo. Por un lado el arreglo raro que poseen los datos de entrada, se debe a que estoy calibrando camaras stereo con tablero de CHARUCO, y tengo que filtrar los elementos que son detectados en cada camara, y dejar unicamente los que se comparten. Quise implementar tu respuesta, pero al usar np.take() me sale el siguiente error: **IndexError: index 36 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22**. el 22 corresponde a la longitud de CORNERSIZQ, pero el 36 no tengo idea. ya que los comunes son 11

Comment: Ahora estoy utilizando otras imagenes de prueba, por lo cual la cantidad de objetos detectados varia, y esa es la idea. La lista de 1 solo elemento inicial se debe a que solo utilizo 1 par de imagenes, de utilizar mas se agregarian elementos a la lista, y quedaria asi: https://easyupload.io/3xf0sc (lo subi en un .txt porque es muy largo). En el caso que utilizase mas imagenes, como deberia iterar esto para obtener esa salida del txt? Lo que mas me preocupa es obtener el mismo formato, dado que sino la funcion cv2.calibratecamera me tira error. como me recomendarias hacerlo? Gracias x ayudarme

Comment: El index error que mencionas en el primer comentario indica que entre la lista de índices comunes que has obtenido, hay uno de valor 36. Es decir, aunque hay 11 comunes, uno de ellos vale 36. Esos valores son los que se usan como índice después sobre las otras matrices. A lo que parece, una de tus matrices tiene solo 22 elementos, por lo que el intento de acceder al índice 36 da error. Me pregunto entonces ¿cómo pudo aparecer el número 36 en los arrays MARKERS si los arrays CORNERS no tienen tantos elementos? Algo anda mal en tus datos de entrada (o yo no estoy entendiendo bien el problema)

Comment: Respecto a la consulta en el segundo comentario, he ampliado la respuesta.